# (preferably free) cross-platform testing software for web developers?

Tags: cross-browser

Hello Stackoverflowers,

Recently I've been working on a website that involves some experimental features that rendered differently on different browsers, platforms and devices.
Is there a good (preferably free) software out there that let's us take out the guesswork in design / dev without actually having to test the website on all devices / platforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) for automated tests, but it won't do the work for you, you have to define the tests and get your CI environment to run them on all relevant platforms.  The good news is that once you set it up it runs automatically and you don't have to manually repeat yourself on each platform.

That's the closest you can get to hassle free testing.